# Close Fancybox 2 width Focus don't work in gallery mode

Tags: jquery, fancybox, focus, fancybox-2

I have a problem with Fancybox 2.
When Fancybox is in gallery mode and that I close the Fancybox with the focus (keyboard enter key), it moves to the second image. I can't close my Fancybox with keyboard (except ESC), it works only with mouse.

You can test this here http://jsfiddle.net/korigan/qfxZd/2/

```
$('.fancybox').click(function(){
       focusLink = this;
   }).fancybox({
    beforeLoad: function() {
        $('a, input, button').attr('tabIndex', -1);
        $('.fancybox-overlay a, .fancybox-overlay button, .fancybox-overlayinput').attr('tabIndex', 0);
    },
    afterClose: function() {
        focusLink.focus();
        $('a, button, input').attr('tabIndex', 0);
    },
});
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Fancybox has the `keys` option to set the behavior of specific pressed keys .... the default for `enter` key is navigate to the `next` image of a gallery from `left`. You can override this behavior by declaring the set of *keys* to move to the `next` image and **omit** the `enter` key (numeric value = `13`) so it will be removed from the stack like :

```
keys: {
    next: {
     // 13: 'left', // enter key will do nothing (left is default behavior)
        34: 'up', // page down
        39: 'left', // right arrow
        40: 'up' // down arrow
    }
}
```

Additionally, you can set the `enter` key to *close* fancybox within the same option like :

```
keys: {
    close: [13], // enter key now closes fancybox
    next: {
     // 13: 'left', // enter doesn't show next image from left
        34: 'up', // page down
        39: 'left', // right arrow
        40: 'up' // down arrow
    }
}
```

... see **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZbfKY/)**